# Xdebug 3 is slow on VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, xdebug

I started to use Xdebug 3 and it works OK but it's very slow. Xdebug 2 was immediately but with Xdebug 3 it takes several seconds until the breakpoint is marked.

Are there some config solution for this problem?

this is my config on `php.ini` file

```ini
[XDebug]

zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.4-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_port = 9003
xdebug.client_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.log = "C:\xampp\tmp\xdebug\xdebug.log"
xdebug.idekey = VSCODE
```

and `launch.json` file

```json
    {
        // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
        // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
        // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
                "type": "php",
                "request": "launch",
                "port": 9003
            },
            {
                "name": "Launch currently open script",
                "type": "php",
                "request": "launch",
                "program": "${file}",
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
                "port": 9003
            }
        ]
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

This is the log, it seems like its nees to try it twite to connect

```
[3560] Log opened at 2021-05-24 09:58:26.404140
[3560] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9003.
[3560] [Step Debug] ERR: Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited: 200 ms. Tried: 127.0.0.1:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(
[8380] Log opened at 2021-05-24 09:58:33.594218
[8380] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9003.
[8380] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: 127.0.0.1:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port). :-)
```

**Update 2:**

this is a complete log

```
[13440] Log opened at 2021-05-24 11:23:49.098251
[13440] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9003.
[13440] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: 127.0.0.1:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port). :-)
[13440] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/prueba/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.4.17RC1" protocol_version="1.0" appid="13440" idekey="VSCODE"><engine version="3.0.4"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2021 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[13440] [Step Debug] <- feature_get -i 1 -n resolved_breakpoints
[13440] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_get" transaction_id="1" feature_name="resolved_breakpoints" supported="1"><![CDATA[0]]></response>

[13440] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 2 -n resolved_breakpoints -v 1
[13440] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="resolved_breakpoints" success="1"></response>

[13440] [Step Debug] <- feature_get -i 3 -n notify_ok
[13440] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_get" transaction_id="3" feature_name="notify_ok" supported="1"><![CDATA[0]]></response>

[13440] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 4 -n notify_ok -v 1
[13440] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="4" feature="notify_ok" success="1"></response>

[13440] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 5 -t line -f file:///c:/xampp/htdocs/prueba/index.php -n 3
[13440] [Step Debug] -> <notify xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" name="breakpoint_resolved"><breakpoint type="line" resolved="resolved" filename="file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/prueba/index.php" lineno="3" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="134400003"></breakpoint></notify>

[13440] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="5" id="134400003" resolved="resolved"></response>

[13440] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_get -i 6 -d 134400003
[13440] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_get" transaction_id="6"><breakpoint type="line" resolved="resolved" filename="file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/prueba/index.php" lineno="3" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="134400003"></breakpoint></response>

[13440] [Step Debug] <- run -i 7
[13440] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="7" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/prueba/index.php" lineno="3"></xdebug:message></response>

[13440] [Step Debug] <- stack_get -i 8
[13440] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="8"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/prueba/index.php" lineno="3"></stack></response>

[13440] [Step Debug] <- context_names -i 9 -d 0
[13440] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_names" transaction_id="9"><context name="Locals" id="0"></context><context name="Superglobals" id="1"></context><context name="User defined constants" id="2"></context></response>

[13440] [Step Debug] <- context_get -i 10 -d 0 -c 0
[13440] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_get" transaction_id="10" context="0"><property name="$saludo" fullname="$saludo" type="uninitialized"></property></response>

[13440] [Step Debug] <- step_into -i 11
[13440] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_into" transaction_id="11" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/prueba/index.php" lineno="4"></xdebug:message></response>

[13440] [Step Debug] <- stack_get -i 12
[13440] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="12"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/prueba/index.php" lineno="4"></stack></response>

[13440] [Step Debug] <- context_names -i 13 -d 0
[13440] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_names" transaction_id="13"><context name="Locals" id="0"></context><context name="Superglobals" id="1"></context><context name="User defined constants" id="2"></context></response>

[13440] [Step Debug] <- context_get -i 14 -d 0 -c 0
[13440] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_get" transaction_id="14" context="0"><property name="$saludo" fullname="$saludo" type="string" size="4" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[aG9sYQ==]]></property></response>

[13440] [Step Debug] <- stop -i 15
[13440] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stop" transaction_id="15" status="stopped" reason="ok"></response>

[13440] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stop" transaction_id="15" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[13440] Log closed at 2021-05-24 11:28:15.536136
```

Comment: What does Xdebug's log say?

Comment: there is no `xdebug.log` file on `C:\xampp\tmp\xdebug\`

Comment: @af_159623 It should generate the log there. Make sure that such folder exists and check for file permissions / antivirus software (just in case). Maybe try another temp folder (e.g. your user temp -- i.e. check `echo %TEMP%` in your cmd.exe terminal). With your settings (`xdebug.start_with_request = yes` in particular) Xdebug should try to debug every single request, so it should be writing the log. Perhaps you have more than 1 PHP or different configs? Double check Xdebug section of the `phpinfo()` output captured in the same way you are trying to debug (CLI or web page).

Comment: @LazyOne, I have updated the question with the log, the first time cannot connect  but the second  attempt works

Comment: So what the response is when it connects? The stuff in the log after that. 1) Maybe it connects to the wrong thing (app)? 2) Maybe VSCode is not yet listening at that time? I may suggest increasing the timeout from default 200ms to something larger (e.g. 1000 or even 2000) and see how it behaves then. https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#connect_timeout_ms

Comment: I've set `xdebug.connect_timeout_ms` now only tries once  but is still slow connecting, once connect works correctly

Comment: Question is updated with a complete log

Comment: Well, the log when it works seems normal to me (at a quick glance). No ideas why there are no response (timeout) on first connection though. Might be: 1) VSCode is not listening at that point yet? Check with `netstat` 2) Still got some previous session active there? (not sure at all on this one though); 3) Maybe some firewall/antivirus related issue. Do you think you can make some screencast (a video) showing how it all works? It may give some clues on what might be happening. Other than that: hope @Derick can give you better ideas on this.

Comment: @LazyOne The log shows a totally normal successful connection, even the breakpoint works (output of `run -i 7`)

Comment: @Derick I meant: why the 1st connection attempt timeout out -- what can cause it? You definitely have seen more complaints/tickets on "it does not connect" than me so may be aware of some specific cases. I'm a PhpStorm user; I've used VSCode just to test/how it works or using it as an editor in those cases where PhpStorm has no good support for that language (a few Python files etc)

Comment: There are either two connections coming in, or perhaps the first one is so fast that VSCode hadn't started listening yet? It's hard to tell without stracing the peep out of it.

Comment: Do you have Google Drive installed with synchronization of the folders where the PHP files are in? Synchronization slows down very much.

Comment: The more breakpoints, the slower xdebug. Try to delete all (xdebug) breakpoints in your project. This works at least for me in phpstorm.